# Resize the images crop the exceeding part

Tags: python, image, crop

I have an image like in resolution `1221 x 821` and I would like to resize it to `1200 x 800` if the part exceeds this range just crop it. Moreover, I want to retain the middle part. How could do it ?

Comment: IF, you are planning to do this in bulk for deep learning, you can consider using ```torchvision.transforms.CentreCrop```

Comment: You can do it without writing any Python by the way. Just use **ImageMagick** in the Terminal `magick INPUT.PNG -gravity center -crop 1200x800+0+0 +repage RESULT.PNG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `opencv` :

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(<>) # 1221 x 821

top=0 # Crop from top
buttom=821 # Crop from buttom
left=0 # Crop from left
right=1221 # Crop from right

cropped_image = img[top:buttom,left:right] # 1221 x 821

cv2.imwrite(cropped_image,<file name>)
```

Or use `PIL` :

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(<>) # 1221 x 821

left=0 # Crop from left
top=0 # Crop from top
right=1221 # Crop from right
buttom=821 # Crop from buttom

im1 = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # 1221 x 821

im1 = im1.save(<>)
```

For more information about it visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-crop-method/)

If you want to get image width and height then for `opencv`

```
dimensions = img.shape
```

> img.shape returns (Height, Width, Number of Channels)
>
> Height represents the number of pixel rows in the image or the number of pixels in each column of the image array.
>
> Width represents the number of pixel columns in the image or the number of pixels in each row of the image array.

And using `PIL` :

```
width, height = im.size
```

> `size` is a `(width, height)` tuple

Comment: isnt that this function has to know the particular are that need to be cropped but in my function, i would like to resize different image every time and do not want to measure the left, right, up, bottom size every time

Comment: if I want to crop the image from 800x450 to 800x448 what should I enter? since I am now in SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image

Comment: @MoJiebu I have added complete description you, I believe you will understand clearly now. How to work with these! If you are still confused then try to play with these values, increase decrease, You will better understand by doing this.

Comment: @MoJiebu if you like my effort you may upvote it as well. :)